# Update input and messages primefaces password on event blur

Tags: ajax, primefaces, blur, message

I am working with primefaces and I have a form with error messages if the form is incomplete. This is part of my form:

```
<h:form id="signup">
  <h1><h:outputText value="Create/Edit"/></h1>
  <h:panelGrid id="panel_signup" columns="3">
    <h:outputLabel value="Email:" for="email" />
    <p:inputText id="email" value="#{loginManagedBean.usuario.email}" title="Email"
                 required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.required}">
      <p:ajax event="blur" update="msgEmail, email" />
    </p:inputText>                    
    <p:message for="email" id="msgEmail" />

    <h:outputLabel value="Password:" for="password" />
    <p:password id="password" value="#{loginManagedBean.usuario.password}"
                title="Password" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.required}">
      <p:ajax event="blur" update="msgPassword, password" />
    </p:password>
    <p:message for="password" id="msgPassword"/>

    <p:commandButton value="Enviar" action="#{loginManagedBean.signup}"
                     update="panel_signup" />
    <p:commandButton value="Limpiar" update="panel_signup" process="@this">
      <p:resetInput target="panel_signup" />
    </p:commandButton>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

This form show the error messages, and with ajax I want to update the messages and the inputs. All work fine except password, because when event blur is trigged and the input is updated, delete the content of password, is there any way to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance!!!

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

try this. but tag f:ajax first

```
 <p:password id="password" value="#{loginManagedBean.usuario.password}"                  title="Password" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.required}">
  <f:ajax execute="@form"/>`
  <p:ajax event="blur" update="msgPassword, password" />
</p:password>
```

Comment: Hi alavaros, sorry, try this. <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@form"  render="@form :messages" listener="#{bean.method}"/>